# Migrating from ASP.NET WebForms to ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webforms, migration, forms-authentication, webmatrix

I'm a student intern and I've been assigned a project where I have to redesign their customer support webpage. I am new to ASP so they asked me to migrate the code to MVC 4 so I'll learn it for future projects.

The webpage has form authentication using custom classes, extending `MembershipProvider` and `RoleProvider` and the data is displayed with `asp:SqlDataSource` queries, defined directly inside .aspx files.

As I've learned, the point of MVC is to separate the front-end (view), controller and back-end (models, db access). I've done some progress towards that, but I have problems at authentication. I've managed to enable login using explicit `MembershipProvider` and `RoleProvider` initialization (which should be done automatically as configured in Web.config). With calling the `MembershipProvider.ValidateUser()` and `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()` I verify user details and store their username to preserve it upon navigation.

This works, but removes all the functionality of `WebSecurity` methods, also the specific authorization, e.g. `[Authorize(Roles = "...")]`, doesn't work as expected, it doesn't authorize any role. The MVC sample project in Visual studio uses `SimpleMembershipProvider` for user authentication, but I haven't found any projects or tutorials on how to implement custom authentication same way as I did with extending `MembershipProvider` class and overriding its methods.

The problem is that there is already a T-SQL database with a lot of users, who are linked to other services, so obviously I can't alter it in any way nor can I create new database / tables. The projects I've looked at create databases from scratch, I haven't found any project using custom authentication / authorization using `WebSecurity` and existing database.

I'd like to ask you for any advices, examples or links to projects or tutorials where I could see how to implement `WebSecurity` instead of `FormsAuthentication`. As I've mentioned, I already have a fully functional `MembershipProvider` and `RoleProvider` and I belive that `SimpleMembershipProvider` and `SimpleRoleProvider` have similar methods, so it shouldn't be that hard on this part. Also, I don't want to mix Webforms and MVC, I want pure MVC application.

*I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 with C# and Razor engine, T-SQL and LINQ to SQL for database access.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been my experience, when migrating old pages from webforms to mvc, that you kind of have to 'forget' that it was ever a webform page to begin with.

to more directly answer your request for help resources, maybe this will be useful: http://kylehodgson.com/2013/01/08/asp-netmvc-web-security-basics-csrf/

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that I'll have to take a whole new approach if I want to do this. And thanks for the link, it's a good article! About the role authorization, I've implemented custom IPrincipal and I've overridden IsInRole to call IsUserInRole from my RoleProvider and now it works like it should.